# Can't "Send To" Thingiverse from Tinkercad.com

Tags: tinkercad, thingiverse

Anyone else seeing this issue? Anyone know a solution?

While editing a part on TinkerCad.com ([this part](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/hrsKxOk1Xc7), to be specific), I click the "Send To" button in the top-right --> click Thingiverse --> I see this screen: [image]

I then click on "Authorize". I'm already signed into Thingiverse, so I click "AGREE & AUTHORIZE APP" --> and I get this error window:

[image]

It states:

> There was a problem authenticating you with Thingiverse
>
> Close this window and return to Tinkercad.
>
> Privacy settings   |
> Privacy/Cookies

Anyone know what could be the issue? I've tried in Google Chrome, on Firefox, in Chrome with incognito mode, and even with a **2nd pair of separate TinkerCad and Thingiverse accounts!** I get the same result each and every time.

Note: I used the Google sign-in for the Thingiverse account. Maybe I need to use the independent account login?

---

Side note: this question is [on-topic](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Websites (could come under Software and/or Tools)
>
> ...
>
> - Issues with web based tools   <=== this one is my question

### I just sent in some support request tickets to both sites

Update 22 Dec. 2021:

I posted a help support ticket to both TinkerCad [here](https://tinkercad.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) (choose "Tinkercad Account" from the "Please choose from the options below" dropdown menu) and to Thingiverse [here](https://www.thingiverse.com/support#) (click link --> choose "Other" from dropdown menu for "What does your support request pertain to?"). I'll add an answer here if I get any useful response or solution from either of them. My support tickets on each site essentially contained the following information:

> ### Subject:
>
> Can't "Send To" Thingiverse from Tinkercad.com
>
> ### Body:
>
> Please see a full description of my problem here: [Can't "Send To" Thingiverse from Tinkercad.com](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/18611/cant-send-to-thingiverse-from-tinkercad-com)
>
> Essentially, no matter what I do I get into an infinite loop of trying to click the "Send to" button to send a model to Thingiverse, and it repeatedly fails with the error shown in the attachment. Again, see the full description at the link above.
>
> ### OS:
>
> Linux Ubuntu 20.04
>
> ### Browser:
>
> Chrome Version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tinkercad replied to my Zendesk ticket I opened (see the question), and as a a result, they seem to have fixed the issue! The "Send To" --> Thingiverse feature seems to be working again!

I sent my request on 20 Dec. 2021:

> ### Subject:
>
> Can't "Send To" Thingiverse from Tinkercad.com
>
> ### Body:
>
> Please see a full description of my problem here: [Can't "Send To" Thingiverse from Tinkercad.com](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/18611/cant-send-to-thingiverse-from-tinkercad-com)
>
> Essentially, no matter what I do I get into an infinite loop of trying to click the "Send to" button to send a model to Thingiverse, and it repeatedly fails with the error shown in the attachment. Again, see the full description at the link above.
>
> ### OS:
>
> Linux Ubuntu 20.04
>
> ### Browser:
>
> Chrome Version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I got this response on 3 Jan. 2022:

> Nicole Smith (Tinkercad)
>
> Jan 3, 2022, 7:16 PST
>
> Hi Gabriel Staples,
>
> Thanks for writing in to let us know about the issue. I'll pass on the information and see what we can figure out.
>
> Regards,
>
> Nicole
> Tinkercad

Then this on 5 Jan. 2022:

> Nicole Smith (Tinkercad)
>
> Jan 5, 2022, 15:40 PST
>
> Hi Gabriel Staples,
>
> This should now be working again.
>
> Regards,
>
> Nicole
> Tinkercad

Sure enough; it seems to be fixed!

Next time you have an issue with TinkerCad, [submit a help request here](https://tinkercad.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) (I chose "Tinkercad Account" from the "Please choose from the options below" dropdown menu).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for the problem is to download your Tinkercad designs and upload them to Thingiverse.

Some people had the same issue and as far as I know, the Tinkercad people are not going to solve it.

Comment: What file types do people most-often prefer? Just `.stl`? Or should I also do `.obj`? What about `.glb`?

Comment: I believe the error is on the Thingiverse side, not Tinkercad.

Comment: I prefer stl, you can also use obj